# How to make an if else-if test for something in a string and delete or change something

Tags: java, arrays, random, int, set

What I am talking about is something like this:

```
if (game == tdm) {
  scoret1 = scoret1 - 100;
}
```

If it helps, my code is listed below:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class codGame {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random me = new Random();
    ArrayList<String> gun = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("KN-44","XR2","HVK-30","ICR-1","Man-O-War","Sheiva","M8A7"));
    ArrayList<String> player = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("BlazeDaBlur","CoolCreeper707","BlurWINSTheGame","QTD","DomIsWhiteTiger","AdvisoryStorm","CadenGaming10","Andrew","gotem","tgg","hahsal","TheOneAndTheOnly20"));
    ArrayList<String> attachments = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Quickdraw","Grip","Extended Mag","Fast Mag","Rapid Fire","Suppressor","Long Barrel"));
    ArrayList<String> optics = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Reflex","Recon","Varix-3","Boa-3","Thermal","ELO"));
    ArrayList<String> maps = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Aquarium","Breach","Combine","Evac","Exodus","Fringe","Havoc","Hunted","Infection","Metro","Redwood","Stronghold","Nuk3town"));
    ArrayList<String> modes = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("TDM","Domination","Free-For-All"));

    List<String> players = Arrays.asList("BlazeDaBlur","CoolCreeper707","BlurWINSTheGame","QTD","DomIsWhiteTiger","AdvisoryStorm","CadenGaming10","Andrew","gotem","tgg","hahsal","TheOneAndTheOnly20");

    Set guns = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(gun));
    Set play = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(player));
    Set att = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(attachments));
    Set opt = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(optics));
    Set map = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(maps));
    Set mode = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(modes));

    Collections.shuffle(players);
    Collections.shuffle(player);
    for (int i=0; i < 11; ++i) {
    player.remove(0);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(gun);
    for (int i=0; i < 6; ++i) {
    gun.remove(0);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(optics);
    for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
    optics.remove(0);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(attachments);
    for (int i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
    attachments.remove(0);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(maps);
    for (int i=0; i < 12; ++i) {
    maps.remove(0);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(modes);
    for (int i=0; i < 2; ++i) {
    modes.remove(0);
    }

    int scoret1 = me.nextInt(200);
    int scoret2 = me.nextInt(200);

    List<String> blackops = players.subList(0, 6);
    List<String> cdp = players.subList(6, 12);

    System.out.println("BlackOps3 game.");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("CDP team: " + cdp);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Black Ops team: " + blackops);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("You are: " + play);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Your gun: " + guns + ", your attachments: " + att + ", and your optic: " + opt);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The map: " + map);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The mode: " + mode);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The score: " + scoret1 + " to " + scoret2);
    }
}
```

To get into a little bit more detail, if you have ever played BO3, you might know that Free-For-All has a score limit of 30, sometimes if I compile this, the gamemode is Free-For-All and I get: score: 180 to 100, which I am trying to fix with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do it inline like this:

```
System.out.println("The score: " + 
(mode.equals("tdm") ? scoret1 - 100 : scoret1) +
" to " + scoret2);
```

Comment: I get this: `bad operand types for binary operator '-'
  first type:  java.lang.String
  second type: int` when i put another `- 100` after scoret2

Comment: So scoret1 is a String, and not an Integer? In that case you would do this: `System.out.println("The score: " + 
(mode.equals("tdm") ? Integer.valueOf(scoret1) - 100 : scoret1) +
" to " + scoret2);`

Otherwise I would need to see the full line to understand what error you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when you're generating random numbers, since you're generating numbers between 0 and 199 (yes, read the Random classes nextInt() method, it returns a number between 0 and the given bound, which is 200 on lines 56 and 57).

If you want to limit it then you need to either check after the number has been generated, or restrict the range based on something. If the user can pick the mode, for example, let's say there's a variable called "gameMode" which is an int, and the user can pick from a few game modes, either use if statements or a switch structure:

```
int bound = 200; //default bound for Random.nextint(bound)

switch(userMode){
    case 1: //user picked game mode 1
        bound = 31; //scores between 0 and 30 
        break;
    case 2: //game mode 2
        bound = 61; //scores between 0 and 60
        break;
    case 3: //game mode 3
        bound = 101;
        break;
    //no default, we already have a default of 200 as the bound
}
```

You can also use if-else statements in a similar fashion, really depends on how many modes, I would say if you have more than 2-3 it's best to use a switch structure or something besides if-else, but it doesn't really matter.

```
int bound = 200;

if(userMode == 1)
    bound = 31;
else if(userMode == 2)
    bound = 61;
else if(userMode == 3)
    bound = 101;
```

Heck, you could even use your little Random object to randomly select the game mode, you can add more code in the if-else or case statements to predefine a "gameModeString" to hold the string for the game mode.

Also, using modulus operators on a random number can limit it's range as well. The modulus operator returns the remainder after dividing the left operand by the right. I.E. 200 % 30 will return 20.

Using a modulus will always follow this form:

A % B is between 0 and B - 1
Therefore anything modulus 30 will return a number between 0 and 29. You can do a mod on the random number such as:

```
int score1 = (me.nextInt(200) % 31); //returns integer between 0 and 30
```

That's about it. I suggest reading a bit more into random number generators (or perusing the Random API in Java), and modulus operations.

Comment: i know that, I was asking for something to make it lower than that if, say free for all was chosen

Comment: And I told you how to do that, you lower the range based on a pre-defined selection choice, such as 0 for free-for-all or 1 for search-and-destroy, or whatever.